# How to modify SpecFlow code generation behaviour

Tags: c#, specflow

We have a feature file with 15061 lines ( auto-generated through another system ).
Specflow (version 3.9.7) manages to generate a cs file through MSbuild task with 39017 lines.
However build of the generated feature file fails with Stack overflow error as:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error : Stack overflow. [D:\Code\DDS_SpecFlow\DDS_SpecFlow.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error : Repeat 24214 times: [D:\Code\DDS_SpecFlow\DDS_SpecFlow.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error : -------------------------------- [D:\Code\DDS_SpecFlow\DDS_SpecFlow.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.InternalSyntax.DirectiveStack.CompleteRegion(Roslyn.Utilities.ConsList`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.InternalSyntax.Directive>) [D:\Code\DDS_SpecFlow\DDS_SpecFlow.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error : -------------------------------- [D:\Code\DDS_SpecFlow\DDS_SpecFlow.csproj]
```

Seems like the number of `#line` directives generated in the file is more than the compiler can handle, since the build succeeds once I remove all of the line directives.

So I am looking a way to configure the SpecFlow code generation task and skip line directive generation.

Comment: Skipping the line directive generation would probably be a temporary fix until the issue re-occurs as the feature file grows. I would take this as a sign that the feature file is too large. Can whichever tool generates the feature file be changed to produce multiple, smaller feature files instead?

Comment: We can do that however it is not a good solution in our case. We are storing our scenarios in Jira group by Functional Areas and generating one feature file per Functional Area to transfer the scripts to our automation system. So in order to make the files smaller, we need to break the functional areas into multiple pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Please split your feature files into multiple files. Any file with 15k lines is unreadable and unmaintainable.

Seb Rose wrote a good article on how to organize your feature files at https://cucumber.io/blog/bdd/solving-how-to-organise-feature-files/

Comment: We are storing the features and scenarios as separate tickets in Jira ( with Zephyr ) so maintenance is not a concern. The feature files are generated on the fly while we are fetching them to our automation platform.